# .Net Socket Stops Working After A Couple Of Uses

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm working on .Net 4 C# application to locate SSDP devices on the network. I have the following code that sends a multicast message via the Socket object asking devices on the network to identify themselves.

```
    using (var identificationRequest = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp))
    {
        identificationRequest.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership,new MulticastOption(multicastAddress));
        identificationRequest.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 2);
        identificationRequest.Connect(new IPEndPoint(multicastAddress, multicastPort));
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(broadcastMessage);
        identificationRequest.Send(message,0, message.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        identificationRequest.Close();
    }
```

This code works great the first few times I run it, however after a couple of runs it stops working. No errors are thrown but if I fire up Wireshark I can see that the packet no longer gets sent. When this happens the only way for me to get this working again is to restart my computer.

There are no loops in the application and the code posted above is called on demand by the user, so its not like I have lots of socket objects hanging around. It usually dies after 4-6 runs.

Any ideas? Is there anything else I should be doing to clean up after each run?

**Edit** : Actually it looks like I don't need to restart and if I leave it a 5 minutes it starts working again.

Comment: Can you run `netstat -b -a -p UDP` from a console when it happens?